# How to debug listeners for ANTLR4 target Go

Tags: go, antlr4

I'm trying to figure out why my listeners aren't triggering for the rules when every rule is being triggered but not the specific rules. I tested my grammar works on http://lab.antlr.org/

Thank you.

this prints...

```
func (f *FSLListener) EnterEveryRule(ctx antlr.ParserRuleContext) {
    fmt.Printf("EnterEveryRule %v\n", ctx.GetText())
}
```

but this doesn't

```
func (f *FSLListener) ExitVar_assignment(ctx *parser.Var_assignmentContext) error {
    fmt.Printf("Complete var assignment: %s\n", ctx.GetText())
    // ... updated this line to reflect that I was handling this error which is why I didn't see any compiler errors
    return nil 
}
```

Following the example listener in https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/go-target.md

My Grammar is

```
parser grammar fslParser;

options { tokenVocab=fslLexer; }


r: script* EOF;

script: var_assignment* init_function function_definition*;

var_assignment: VAR VALUE;
init_function: INIT cmd_list RBRACK;
function_definition: VALIDFUNCTIONID cmd_list RBRACK;

cmd_list: (cmd_expression)*;

cmd_expression:
  CMD FUNCTIONCALL
  | CMD FUNCTIONCALLWITHARGS param_list //function call
  | CMD VARREF COMMA param_list // variable reference
  | CMD builtin_functions param_list // user-defined function call
;

builtin_functions: (CREATE | DELETE | UPDATE | ADD | SUBTRACT | MULTIPLY | DIVIDE | PRINT);

param_list: ARG param (COMMA ARG param)*;
param:
  VARREF
  | VALUE
  | LETTERS VALUE
  | VARPARAM
  | VARPARAM VALUE
;
```

Lexer

```
lexer grammar fslLexer;

INIT : 'init: [' ;
VALIDFUNCTIONID : [a-zA-Z]+ ': [';
VAR : 'var' [0-9]+':' ;
VALUE : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)? ;
CMD : 'cmd:' ;
VARREF : '#var'[0-9]+ ;
FUNCTIONCALL : '#' [a-zA-Z]+ ;
FUNCTIONCALLWITHARGS : '#' [a-zA-Z]+',' ;
VARPARAM : '$' [a-zA-Z]+ ;

DIGITS: [0-9]+;
LETTERS: [a-zA-Z]+;

ARG: LETTERS DIGITS? COLON;

// Define function names as keywords
CREATE  : 'create,' ;
DELETE  : 'delete,' ;
UPDATE  : 'update,' ;
ADD     : 'add,' ;
SUBTRACT: 'subtract,' ;
MULTIPLY: 'multiply,' ;
DIVIDE  : 'divide,' ;
PRINT   : 'print,' ;

COLON : ':';
COMMA : ',';
RBRACK : ']';

SPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Example input I'm trying to match:

```
var1: 1
var2: 2

init: [
    cmd: #setup
]

setup: [
    cmd: #sum, id: var1, value1: #var1, value2: #var2
    cmd: #printAll
]

sum: [
   cmd: add, id: $id, operand1: $value1, operand2: $value2
]

printAll: [
   cmd: print, value: #var1
   cmd: print, value: #var2
   cmd: print, value: #var3
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
func (f *FSLListener) ExitVar_assignment(ctx *parser.Var_assignmentContext) error {
    fmt.Printf("Complete var assignment: %s\n", ctx.GetText())
}
```

Should be:

```golang
func (f *FSLListener) ExitVar_assignment(ctx *parser.Var_assignmentContext) {
    fmt.Printf("Complete var assignment: %s\n", ctx.GetText())
}
```

This is a simple syntax error in the Go code. The implementation does not have a return value. After applying this change, I can see this output:

```
Complete var assignment: var1:1
Complete var assignment: var2:2
```

And please note that the generated `fslParserListener` interface is:

```golang
// fslParserListener is a complete listener for a parse tree produced by fslParser.
type fslParserListener interface {
    // ExitVar_assignment is called when exiting the var_assignment production.
    ExitVar_assignment(c *Var_assignmentContext)

    // Other codes truncated
}
```

It does not have a return value.

To force the interface compliance, you can export the listener interface and add this statement to your  code (it assumes that the interface is exported as `parser.FslParserListener`):

```golang
var _ parser.FslParserListener = (*FSLListener)(nil)
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you, that fixed all of them!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is it possible that you did not notice the compile time error?

Comment: Oh, that's because in my actual code, I was handling the error but I just didn't copy the whole function into this question for simplicity. Funny enough all the other listener methods had the right interface but just this one being wrong broke all the others too! (updated the question to match what I was seeing wasn't a compiler error)

Comment: @Laura I have updated the answer to add a trick to force interface compliance. Please take a look.